# TypeScript: __dirname value?

Tags: typescript

My folder structure is like this:

```
app
└─ tsFolder
   └─ XX.ts
```

Code in `XX.ts` file:

```js
var __dirname: string;
console.log("__dirname: " + __dirname); // the output is undefined.
```

I have tried it: by comment out the code `var __dirname: string;`, the value of `__dirname` is: `...../app` insead of pointing to the current folder like `...../app/tsFolder`.

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 45):

Just run

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

And if that doesn't work on its own, add

```
"types": ["node"]
```

to your `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` field.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you refer to NodeJS global variable [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

If it points to the `..../app` it means that your `XX.ts` is compiled to the `..../app` folder. And when the resulting js file is run:
`__dirname` points to its (`js` file) location.

And of course, you should not declare new var `__dirname`.

Instead, either use NodeJS [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts) or just declare it manually like this:

```
declare var __dirname;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Actually XX.ts is under tsFolder and after compiled, its .js and .js.map files are all under tsFolder. Another question is: what's the difference between `declare var __dirname;` and `var __dirname`?

Comment: Can you post how you start your compiled js file. The difference between two is that `var __dirname` defines new variable that overrides the one provided by nodejs. Therefore the value is undefined. While second says that this variable is defined somewhere else so typescript compiler will not complain of it being undeclared. See more for example here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/variables.html

Answer (score 2):

I have tried:

```sh
npm i @types/node
```

with no change in `tsconfig`.

You make sure that the working directory path length must be less than the windows maximum limit.

Comment: you should instead install them a Dev Dependency as you don't need `Typescript types` in production with `npm i -D @types/node`

Answer (score -3):

you have created a new variable called "__dirname" which has no value and overrides a variable with the same name provided by nodejs

remove the declaration and it will work