# __dirname in typescript for nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

This is the first time I'm using typescript in my node project.
my directory structure looks like this

```
root
  src // typescript files
    index.ts

  build // compiled js files
    src
      index.js

  storage  // storage for media
```

I'm outputting my compiled javascript into ./build

now, In my index.ts file, I have

```
  fs.existsSync(resolve(__dirname, '../storage'))
```

This works when i'm running nodemon with ts-node and of course fails when I run javascript output from build.

I believe there's a way to tell typescript to process these files according to tsconfig.compilerOptions.outDir

or compile as `srcNew/index.js` instead of `build/src/index.js` but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316118/typescript-dirname-value#36316983

Comment: @özkir in my case __dirname does return a value in index.js its not undefined. But it’s different from the one I get in the index.ts. And I get that. I need a way to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,

Turns out this is a behaviour of typescript compiler.
And you should only set `tsconfig.compilerOptions.rootDir` when you want your current directory structure to be ***a part*** of the `tsconfig.compilerOptions.outDir` directory. Otherwise it would copy your current directory struture into `outDir` as it is.

[You can read more about it here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir)